# What makes the "Add article" form in this Laravel 8 application fail?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am making a blogging application with *Laravel 8* and Bootstrap 5.

I run into a problem with adding an article into the `articles` table.

In the migration file that generated the `articles` table, I have:

```
public function up() {
 Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('catergories');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->string('short_description');
    $table->longText('content');
    $table->tinyInteger('featured')->default('0');
    $table->string('image')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

In the `Article` model, I have:

```
class Article extends Model {
  use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'category_id',
        'title',
        'slug',
        'short_description',
        'content',
        'featured',
        'image',
    ];

    // Join users to articles
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    // Join categories to articles
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(ArticleCategory::class);
    }
}
```

In the controller, I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\ArticleCategory;
use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller {
    private $rules = [
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:article_categories,id',
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'short_description' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'image' =>  'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        'content' => 'required|string',
        'featured' => 'required'
    ];

    private $messages = [
        'category_id.required' => 'Please pick a category for the article',
        'title.required' => 'Please provide a title for the article',
        'short_description.required' => 'The article needs a short description',
        'content.required' => 'Please add content'
    ];
    
    public function categories() {
        return ArticleCategory::all();
    }
    
    public function index() {
        $articles = Article::paginate(10);

        return view('dashboard/articles',
            ['articles' => $articles]
        );
    }

    public function create() {
        // Load the view and populate the form with categories
        return view('dashboard/add-article',
            ['categories' => $this->categories()]
        );
    }

    public function save(Request $request) {

        // Validate form (with custom messages)
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules, $this->messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
        }

        $fields = $validator->validated();

        // Upload article image
        $current_user = Auth::user();

        if (isset($request->image)) {
            $imageName = md5(time()) . $current_user->id . '.' . $request->image->extension();
            $request->image->move(public_path('images/articles'), $imageName);
        }

        // Data to be added
        $form_data = [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => $fields['category_id'],
            'title' => $fields['title'],
            'slug' => Str::slug($fields['title'], '-'),
            'short_description' => $fields['short_description'],
            'content' => $fields['content'],
            'image' => $fields['image'],
            'featured' => $fields['featured']
        ];

        // Insert data in the 'articles' table
        $query = Article::create($form_data);

        if ($query) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.articles')->with('success', 'Article added');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Adding article failed');
        }
    }
}
```

The form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('dashboard.articles.add') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    @csrf
    <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Title') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-12 @error('title') has-error @enderror">
                    <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" autocomplete="title" autofocus>

                    @error('title')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="short_description" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Short description') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-12 @error('short_description') has-error @enderror">
                    <input id="short_description" type="text" placeholder="Short description" class="form-control @error('short_description') is-invalid @enderror" name="short_description" value="{{ old('short_description') }}" autocomplete="short_description" autofocus>

                    @error('short_description')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="category" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Category') }}</label>
    
        <div class="col-md-12 @error('category_id') has-error @enderror">
    
            <select name="category_id" id="category" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                <option value="0">Pick a category</option>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
                
                @error('category_id')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center switch-toggle">
                <p class="mb-0 me-3">Featured article?</p>
                <input class="mt-1" type="checkbox" name="featured" id="featured">
                <label class="px-1" for="featured">{{ __('Toggle') }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="image" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Article image') }}</label>
    
        <div class="col-md-12 @error('image') has-error @enderror">
            <input type="file" name="image" id="file" class="file-upload-btn">
    
            @error('image')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="content" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Content') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-12 @error('content') has-error @enderror">

            <textarea name="content" id="content" class="form-control @error('content') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Content" cols="30" rows="6">{{ old('content') }}</textarea>

            @error('content')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('Save') }}
                    </button>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The routes:

```
// Article routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'articles'], function() {
  Route::get('/', [ArticleController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.articles');
  Route::get('/new', [ArticleController::class, 'create'])->name('dashboard.articles.new');
  Route::post('/add', [ArticleController::class, 'save'])->name('dashboard.articles.add');
});
```

#### The problem:

Even though the form passes validation, and a redirect occurs, the record is not actually added to the `articles` table.

Laravel throws the error `General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column 'featured' at row 1`.

##### What is my mistake?

Comment: a checkbox has a default value of `'on'`; you should set a value on the checkbox to the value you need for it, `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with checkboxes you need to know that;

a) you cannot use `required` since the checkbox is not sent with the form data if it is unchecked.

b) the default value is 'on' but actually, the presence of the field in the data means it was checked so what I normally do is like;

```
'featured' => $request->has('featured')
```

this will return a boolean true or false, suitable for storing in your db

So you could write

```
        // Turn the 'featured' field value into a tiny integer
        //$fields['featured'] = $request->get('featured') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;

        // If no image is uploaded, use default.jpg
        $fields['image'] = $request->get('image') == '' ? 'default.jpg' : $imageName;

        // Data to be added
        $form_data = [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => $fields['category_id'],
            'title' => $fields['title'],
            'slug' => Str::slug($fields['title'], '-'),
            'short_description' => $fields['short_description'],
            'content' => $fields['content'],
            'featured' => $request->has('featured'),
            'image' => $fields['image']
        ];
```

Comment: Replacing `'featured' => 'required'` with `'featured' => $request->has('featured')` results in a `Constant expression contains invalid operations` error. What I need is a tiny integer.

Comment: Not in the validation; do it in your `$form_data = [...` section

Comment: remove it from validation.  the code change is where you save the data

Comment: The default value of the checkbox being "on", I used this: `$fields['featured'] = $fields['featured'] == 'on' ? 1 : 0;`. You can update your answer, if you want. Thanks!

Comment: In case it helps (or satisfies your curiosity), **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71636571/4512005)** is the full working code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I edited my answer. Your method of testing the featured flag is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Your column is defined as a `tinyInteger` that can only accept a single digit, but you seem to be passing a string `on` to it.

`$table->tinyInteger('featured')->default('0');`

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column
> 'featured' at row 1

Try setting the value of your checkbox to `1`.

```
<input class="mt-1" type="checkbox" name="featured" id="featured" value="1">
```

---

Edit, make sure to add `boolean` to your validation rules after adding the value to your input element.

```
private $rules = [
    'category_id' => 'required|exists:article_categories,id',
    'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'short_description' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'image' =>  'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    'content' => 'required|string',
    'featured' => 'required|boolean'
];
```

Comment: So it should be `$table->tinyInteger('featured')->default(0);`?

Comment: he made ```tinyinteger``` as Boolean and i think it can work fine

Comment: Does not solve the problem.

Comment: In case it helps (or satisfies your curiosity), **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71636571/4512005)** is the full working code. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, here is the working code for creating an article:

The routes:

```
// Article routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'articles'], function() {
  Route::get('/', [ArticleController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.articles');
  Route::get('/new', [ArticleController::class, 'create'])->name('dashboard.articles.new');
  Route::post('/add', [ArticleController::class, 'save'])->name('dashboard.articles.add');
});
```

In the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\ArticleCategory;
use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    
    private $rules = [
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:article_categories,id',
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'short_description' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'image' =>  'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        'content' => 'required|string'
    ];

    private $messages = [
        'category_id.required' => 'Please pick a category for the article',
        'title.required' => 'Please provide a title for the article',
        'short_description.required' => 'The article needs a short description',
        'content.required' => 'Please add content'
    ];
    
    public function categories() {
        return ArticleCategory::all();
    }
    
    public function index() {
        $articles = Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        return view('dashboard/articles',
            ['articles' => $articles]
        );
    }

    public function create() {
        // Load the view and populate the form with categories
        return view('dashboard/add-article',
            ['categories' => $this->categories()]
        );
    }

    public function save(Request $request) {

        // Validate form (with custom messages)
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules, $this->messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
        }

        $fields = $validator->validated();

        // Upload article image
        $current_user = Auth::user();

        if (isset($request->image)) {
            $imageName = md5(time()) . $current_user->id . '.' . $request->image->extension();
            $request->image->move(public_path('images/articles'), $imageName);
        }

        // Turn the 'featured' field value into a tiny integer
        $fields['featured'] = $request->get('featured') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;

        // If no image is uploaded, use default.jpg
        $fields['image'] = $request->get('image') == '' ? 'default.jpg' : $imageName;

        // Data to be added
        $form_data = [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => $fields['category_id'],
            'title' => $fields['title'],
            'slug' => Str::slug($fields['title'], '-'),
            'short_description' => $fields['short_description'],
            'content' => $fields['content'],
            'featured' => $fields['featured'],
            'image' => $fields['image']
        ];

        // Insert data in the 'articles' table
        $query = Article::create($form_data);

        if ($query) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.articles')->with('success', 'Article added');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Adding article failed');
        }
    }
}
```